# Grouping documents by week/month/year using Node js

Tags: node.js, date, group-by, mean

I am currently developing a cash register app. I am using a model-controller-view-repository design.  I have a cart model that holds products, and when a sale is validated, it clones the cart and adds a date.
My question is: how can I get all the sales done in a specific period of time in a given year.
Example of what I want: «http://localhost:PORT/sales/month/3» would get all sales done in march, « http://localhost:PORT/sales/month/3/week/1 » would get all sales done in the first week of march etc...
I tried several things but I am still lost in MEAN stack. Thanks, I hope my post is not too confusing

EDIT: with some more understanding, I managed to list what I wanted, but I currently no idea how to implement it using my design. Here is the code:

```
db.ventes.aggregate( 
    {$project : { 
        month : {$month : "$dateVente"}, 
        year :{$year :  "$dateVente"},
        _id : 1
    }}, 
    {$match : {month : 1 ,year : 2021 }
    }
 )
```

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: I tried several requests I found on stackoverflow, some counting the entries within a specific year/month/week, and some sorting the entries, but I couldn’t find a solution to get an array of documents. I tried using agregate and $group, and I didn’t even manage to get what I wanted using only mongo, let alone node js. I would appreciate tips on how I should proceed to resolve this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution.

This is my repository:

```
exports.findByMonth = async payload => {
  return await Vente.aggregate([
      {$project : {
        date: "$dateVente",
        month : {$month : "$dateVente"},
        year : {$year :  "$dateVente"},
        subTotal: 1,
        _id : 1
      }},
   {$match : {month : payload.month ,year : payload.year }}
    ]
  )
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
exports.getVenteByMonth = async (req, res) => {
        try {
            let targetDate = {
                month: req.body.month,
                year: req.body.year
            }
            let ventesByMonth = await venteRepository.findByMonth(targetDate)
            res.status(200).json({
                status: true,
                data: ventesByMonth
            })

        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                status: false,
                error: err
            })
        }
    }
```

This is the result:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "600ab585a16ea2072ce0e0f5",
            "subTotal": 196,
            "date": "2021-01-22T11:22:40.876Z",
            "month": 1,
            "year": 2021
        },
        {
            "_id": "600c391b5b0612027d9f75c2",
            "subTotal": 115,
            "date": "2021-01-23T14:46:14.846Z",
            "month": 1,
            "year": 2021
        },
        {
            "_id": "600c3bdf2cca74037320520f",
            "subTotal": 0,
            "date": "2021-01-23T15:08:10.683Z",
            "month": 1,
            "year": 2021
        },
        {
            "_id": "600c3fd76acde803e589c7ff",
            "subTotal": 147,
            "date": "2021-01-23T15:25:02.032Z",
            "month": 1,
            "year": 2021
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my route:

```
router.get("/monthly", venteController.getVenteByMonth);
```

I would appreciate if anyone had time to comment on how I organized my files, and if it makes any sense at all, or if there is any "cleaner" way to do so, thanks !